# Get value of button in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to get the set value from a button to further procces this in my function.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[Student.Absence]]">
        <td><button class="defaultbutton" value="[[Student.studentnum]]"></button></td>
        <td><button class="absentbutton" value="[[Student.studentnum]]" on-click="absenceHandler(this.value)"></button></td>
     </template>




 absenceHandler(studID){
    let DummyStudents = this.get(['DummyStudents']);
    console.log(studID);
    alert(DummyStudents[1]);
  }
```

I expect the value to be inserted into my function but instead i get this:

listener method `absenceHandler(this.value)` not defined
handler @ template-stamp.html:98
(anonymous) @ templatize.html:160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of sending the value to the method explicitly. You can make it work as follows.

```
 <td><button class="absentbutton" value="[[Student.studentnum]]" on-click="absenceHandler"></button></td>


absenceHandler(e){
let studID = e.currentTarget.value;
    let DummyStudents = this.get(['DummyStudents']);
    console.log(studID);
    alert(DummyStudents[1]);
  }
```

Comment: Also;  `this.Student.studentnum` gives the same :)

Comment: Thank you it did indead work. However i do not completely understand why you give the function a parameter? Or how exactly it functions.

Comment: That parameter will be implicitly passed as the event which has called this function. So here it is mouseEvent and that will have all the data related to button and its attributes.